# Access denied for User MVC Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller

Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: No) rolemanager mvc

Getting error for **IsInRole**, I am using Mysql with EF6

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Consumer"))
{

}
```

Error log:

> [MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)] MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>   +309 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
>   +39
>
> [MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host '' for user ''
>   using    method  'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access
>   denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)]
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.
>   AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex) +179
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
>   +64 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate
>   (Boolean reset) +381
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod,
>   Boolean reset) +71 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +831
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings) +239
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +11
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +288
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +641
>   MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
>   +63 System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +199 ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Menu_cshtml.Execute() in
>   C:\Code\Studio-NI\Studio-NI\Views\Shared_Menu.cshtml:23

Comment: Please provide your db connection string, and also <entityFramework> settings